# Footnote 1 by 1

Tags: beamer, footnotes

1. I have "4 items" in "Frame 1" of the beamer.
2. I have the same "reference 1" for "item 1 and item 2", "item 3" has no reference, and "item 4" has a reference.
3. I want that each reference in the footnote appear with its item where its mentioned and also no reference to repeat itself in the footnote.
4. For example- I need "reference 1" as a footnote in slide 1,slide 2, and slide 3, but at slide 4, I need both "reference 1 and reference 2" as a footnote.

How to Do this.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{List in Beamer}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item A\footnote{\label{1}reference 1.}
\pause
\item Item B{$^{\ref{1}}$}
\pause
\item Item C
\pause
\item Item D\footnote{reference 4.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beamer footnotes are overlay aware. You can control via overlays on which slides they should appear:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{List in Beamer}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item Item A\footnote<1->{\label{1}reference 1.}
\item Item B\footnotemark[1]
\item Item C
\item Item D\footnote<4->{reference 4.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 4. For example- I need "reference 1" as a footnote in slide 1,slide 2, and slide 3, but on slide 4, I need both "reference 1 and reference 2" as a footnote.

Comment: @DauoodSaleem Updated